# Github OAuth Ignoring Scope Parameter in URL, Can't List Private Repos

Tags: oauth, github-api

This is for a "GitHub App"not an "OAuth App".
I'm trying to list private repos from the user.

I specify scope in URL
[image]

I specify permissions in GitHub App:

[image]

[image]

[image: , ca]

OAuth page does not show correct permissions

[image]

GitHub returns no scope from final OAuth step:

```
access_token: 'xxxxx'
scope: ''
token_type: 'bearer'
```

Answer (score 2):

Scope is not a parameter for the GitHub App OAuth endpoint. It is only used for OAuth apps See https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.16/apps/building-github-apps/identifying-and-authorizing-users-for-github-apps/